# Shall migrating to PKCS12 for apk upload key?

Tags: android, apk

When [generating upload key](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android) for Android apk with the command below:

```
$ keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore my-key.keystore -alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

there is a warning message:

```
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore my-key.keystore -destkeystore my-key.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

What is the benefit of migrating?

Comment: Isn't the Warning instructive enough?